# Git creates directory symlink as a file

Tags: git, symlink

Given two normal folders in a repo:

```bash
drwx------ dir_a/
drwx------ dir_b/
```

I convert `dir_b` to a relative symlink pointing to `dir_a` (i.e. `rm -rf dir_b` and `ln -s dir_a dir_b` so that now it looks like:

```bash
drwx------ dir_a/
lrwxrwxrwx dir_b -> dir_a/
```

After committing, pushing and pulling on another machine I see `dir_b` shown as a normal file and not as a folder symlink

```bash
$ ls -al
drwx------ dir_a/
-rw------- dir_b
```

Tried removing `dir_b` and restoring it with `git checkout dir_b` but it is still recreated as a file, and not a folder symlink. The file system is ext4 which supports symlinks. In fact, doing a fresh `git clone` on the same partition does create `dir_b` as a symlink as expected.

In case it could matter I'll mention that the actual name of `dir_b` starts with a dot (e.g. `.dir_b`).

`git clone` works correctly, so I could use it as a workaround, but would like to know what exactly is happening and what's the correct way to restore symlinked folders since apparently `git checkout symlinked_folder` does not recreate the folder as in the original repo.

Comment: If `git clone` works correctly and you haven't disabled symlinks in the repository where things are failing, that seems like a straight bug. If you *have* disabled symlinks (by setting `core.symlinks` to `false`), just re-enable them.

Comment: @torek: `git config -l | grep symlinks` returns `core.symlinks=false`

Comment: Well, that's the problem then. Configure it back to `true` and all should work again. Note that the `git config` documentation claims (quote) "The default is true, except git-clone(1) or git-init(1) will probe and set `core.symlinks` false if appropriate when the repository is created."

Comment: Did a `git config --global core.symlinks true` and repeated without `--global` just for the repo, and `git checkout dir_b` worked. Now I realized what happened: I originally cloned to the phone's sdcard which is FAT so the symlinks were set to false, then I moved the repo to the internal EXT4 partition. Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: BTW you shouldn't set this with `--global` at all, as it's meant to be per-repository (like `core.bare` and `core.repositoryformatversion`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fix in this case was to run:

```
git config core.symlinks true
```

(It may be wise to check for other non-default settings, especially if the SD-card repository was created by a different OS.)

As discussed in comments, the key element here was that the repository was originally created on a non-symlink-supporting file system, and then moved (copied manually) to a symlink-supporting file system.  [The `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html), down in the section describing `core.symlinks`, says:

> If false, symbolic links are checked out as small plain files that contain the link text. [git-update-index(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html) and [git-add(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html) will not change the recorded type to regular file. Useful on filesystems like FAT that do not support symbolic links.
>
> The default is true, except [git-clone(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html) or [git-init(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html) will probe and set core.symlinks false if appropriate when the repository is created.

In general, it's a little bit safer to `git clone` a repository when moving it across logical or physical drives, since the new clone will probe the new file system's settings.  Git is fairly good at autodetecting other changes (e.g., the index encodes the work-tree path) and most of these settings are OS-specific rather than file-system-specific.  If you cross-boot different OSes (or run them under hypervisors) and share some media between then, though, these additional `core.*` settings may cause issues.  See, e.g., `core.fileMode` and `core.protectNTFS`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint regarding `filemode`! I did notice inconsistencies with the executable flag not being set when pulling from another clone and now I know why. btw, in my `.git/config` it is listed as `core.filemode` (all lowercase), but I assume config options are probably case-insensitive.

Comment: Yes, they're all reduced to lowercase before comparing. (This reduction direction is critical in some languages, although German recently required an uppercase ß; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_%E1%BA%9E. At the same time, though, all of Git's built in configuration variables are ASCII-encoded, so uppercase would actually suffice...)